# Button click event on $.post-loaded button

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, load

After filling a div with a `$(myDiv).load()` call, I want to catch the click event on the button inside that div.

Now for some reason my `$('.myButton').click` is not invoked when I click on a button that is loaded through jQuery's load function.

What is the best way around this?

Comment: The button won't be loaded until the load is complete. Try adding the event handler decleration in the complete method of the load call.

Comment: I want it to be general, not per-button. When a button has the class .modulesubmit, I want jQuery to send a form in the module, and show the result, in the same div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch an event of a dynamic object, to do this you have to use `.on()`
try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myButton', function(){
  //your code
});
```

instead of

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
  //your code
});
```